# Beamer: Absolute Positioning of Picture | Unexpected Padding

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning

- I want to place/position images/pictures/elements in `beamer` absolutely.
- I use the well known `remember picture` and `\node at (current page.xx)` appraoch.

In my MWE I want to position the picture in the **lower right corner** of the frame but there is a unexpected **"padding" remaining**.

---

```
% Compile twice (--> 'remember picture' option)!
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

% Setting background to "not-white" in order to make the borders clearer.
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg = green}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Test}
Test

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture] 
    %
    \node at (current page.south east) [anchor = south east] {
    \includegraphics[width = 60mm]{example-image-a}
    };
    %
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Update 1 after user [erik's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/24974) Comment

- Adding `inner sep = 0pt` to `\node at (current page.south east) [anchor = south east, inner sep = 0pt]` almost solves the problem.
- There is still a bit padding left, or is this a viewer problem?

### [image]

### Update 2 after user [marmot's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799) Comment

**Final solution!**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

% Setting background to not white in order to make the borders clearer.
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg = green}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Test}
Test

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture] 
    %
    \node at (current page.south east) [
        anchor = south east, 
        inner sep = 0pt, % <-- Solution
        outer sep = 0pt, % <-- Solution
        ] {
    \includegraphics[width = 60mm]{example-image-a}
    };
    %
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `inner sep=0pt` and `outer sep=0pt` to your `tikzpicture` options.

Comment: @erik Thanks! I updated the question. If you provide an answer, then I will at least upvote it and probably accept if there is nothing else to optimize.

Comment: @marmot Thanks! I did not think of the `inner/outer sep` stuff in this context. I was unable to Google my problem before -- but I can't be the first one to encounter this "problem" :).

Comment: @erik I am offline now -- I will accept your answer later if you provide one.

Comment: @marmot I am offline now -- I will upvote your answer later if you provide one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ti*k*Z automatically adds a bit of space around nodes. Most of the space is due to `inner sep`, but there's a very small `outer sep` as well (analogous to padding and margin in CSS, I think). You can remove this by setting `inner sep=0` and `outer sep=0`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
% Setting background to "not-white" in order to make the borders clearer.
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg = green}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Test}
Test

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture] 
    \node at (current page.south east) [anchor = south east,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] {
    \includegraphics[width = 60mm]{example-image-a}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]